# Find Orders with exact number of items count - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all thanks for your help.

I have 2 tables, one with orders and the other one with items bought.

Example:

**ORDER**:

```
ID 
---
1
2
3
4
```

**ORDER_ITEMS**:

```
ID | ORDER_ID | ITEM_ID
---+----------+---------
1  |    1     |   1
2  |    1     |   1
3  |    1     |   2
4  |    1     |   3
5  |    2     |   1
6  |    2     |   2
7  |    2     |   3
8  |    3     |   1
9  |    3     |   1
10 |    3     |   2
11 |    3     |   3
```

In this case all orders have the same items, but only 2 of them have the same amount of each item.

What I need is that for a given input of `ITEM_ID` I can get the `ORDER_ID`.

Example:

- input = (1,1,2,3) -> OUTPUT = 1, 3
- input = (1,2,3) -> OUTPUT = 2

I have the following query to get the order, item, count:

```
SELECT 
    O.ORDER_ID, I.ITEM_ID, count(I.ITEM_ID) 
FROM 
    ORDER AS O
INNER JOIN 
    ORDER_ITEM AS I ON O.ORDER_ID = I.ORDER_ID 
GROUP BY 
    O.ORDER_ID, I.ITEM_ID
ORDER BY 
    O.ORDER_ID
```

With the following output:

```
ORDER_ID | ITEM_ID  | COUNT
---------+----------+------
    1    |    1     |   2
    1    |    2     |   1
    1    |    3     |   1
    2    |    1     |   1
    2    |    2     |   1
    2    |    3     |   1
    3    |    1     |   2
    3    |    2     |   1
    3    |    3     |   1
```

This is an example input and how i treat it, function just splits the string by ','

```
    DECLARE @ITEM_ID VARCHAR(255)
    SET @ITEM_ID = '1,1,2,3'
    SELECT DISTINCT(R.sID), COUNT(R.sID) FROM CommaSeparatedToString(@ITEM_ID ) AS R 
GROUP BY R.sID

   sID  |  COUNT
    1   |   2 
    2   |   1
    3   |   1
```

With what I already have, how can I achieve the desired output? In this case it would be orders 1 and 3.

Thanks again.

Comment: I follow this clearly until you start talking your function. Not sure what that has to do with the rest of the question. Are you asking how you can count the number of like values in a comma delimited string?

Comment: i think he wants to put the logic into a function. InsertParameter the comma separated values, Output the OrderIDs

Comment: Since 90% of your question here appears to be just noise and all you are asking about is the output from your function can you share your function? This is super simple with most string splitters.

Comment: You can just forget the function, i need a query to return order 1 and 3, given the items input 1,1,2,3.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry for the confusion, you can forget the function, it's only use is to transform a varchar into sth that can be used in a `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE IN (SELECT ID FROM CommaSeparatedToString('1, 2, 3'))` , again sorry for introducing this since it was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you may have duplication items in the same order, you could add a row number as identifier

```
WITH order AS (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) as rn from CommaSeparatedToString(@ITEM_ID )) 
,
i AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ORDER_ID] ORDER BY [ITEM_ID] ASC) as rn from ORDER_ITEMS)
SELECT  i.ORDER_ID
FROM  i
LEFT JOIN order o
  ON o.ID = i.ITEM_ID AND i.rn = o.rn
GROUP BY i.ORDER_ID
HAVING 
    COUNT(i.ID) = COUNT(o.rn)  -- ORDER_ITEMS match every order in the order list
  AND 
    COUNT(i.ID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) from order) -- ORDER_ITEMS have exact number of the order list
```

Comment: Perfect, and it solves the problem that the answer from @GordonLinoff had regarding the order in the input.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to provide input as "1,1,2,3", then the simplest solution is to aggregation the values:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             stuff( (select ',' + cast(oi.item_id as varchar(255))
                     from order_items oi
                     where oi.order_id = o.id
                     order by oi.item_id
                     for xml path ('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') as items
      from orders o
     ) o
where items in ('1,1,2,3');
```

Comment: I'm getting error sintaxis around `order` http://rextester.com/NGCTF4756

Comment: just remove the "order by"

Comment: @EstebanP. Nope, the order is important. The issue is the order should be before the `for xml path` now is working perfectly. http://rextester.com/RVQ34195

Comment: @Acorian0 just be aware your input should also be order by id or this wont work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, I was doing group by and joins trying to do the same

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's like 90% of what i need, and very thankfully for it :) If not asking too much...  if the input is 1, 2, 3, 1 and i want the output to be the same, what can i do? Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Acorian0 . . . You will need to order the input in order for this method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from where you have got - my #counts table is your count by order and item, my #findme is the output of your last query representing what you are searching for.

```
create table #counts
(
    order_id int,
    item_id int,
    cnt int
);

insert into #counts values
   (1, 1 ,2),
   (1, 2 ,1),
   (1, 3 ,1),
   (2, 1 ,1),
   (2, 2 ,1),
   (2, 3 ,1),
   (3, 1 ,2),
   (3, 2 ,1),
   (3, 3 ,1);

create table #findme
(
    item_id int,
    cnt int
);

insert into #findme values
  (1,2),
  (2,1),
  (3,1);

-- get count of different items per order
select order_id,
  count(*) as cnt
into #itemcnt
from #counts
group by order_id

-- now join our search query and see how many rows match on both item and count
select order_id, count(*) cnt
into #found
from #findme
inner join #counts 
    on #findme.item_id = #counts.item_id
   and #findme.cnt = #counts.cnt
group by order_id

-- now join this to see where number of matches = number of different items
select distinct #found.order_id
from #found
inner join #itemcnt on #found.cnt = #itemcnt.cnt
```